# How can I insert an HTML url in Chtml Button

Tags: php, html, yii

I want to insert a button with an external link to another website.
Is it possible to do that using a CHtml Button ? if not how can I do it ?
thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done by `CHtml` button. Example here...

```
CHtml::button(
    'Link',
    array(
        'class'=>'btn',
        'onclick'=>"window.open('//google.com')",
    )
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<?php echo CHtml::link('Link Text','http://google.com',array('target'=>'_blank','class'=>'btn_registro')); ?>
```

Apply this css

```
.btn_registro {
  font: bold 11px Arial;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  color: #333333;
  padding: 2px 6px 2px 6px;
  border-top: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  border-right: 1px solid #333333;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #333333;
  border-left: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
}
```

Comment: but it doesn't creat a Button, what I want it's like a search button who takes you to another website

Comment: i have edited my answer now it has class btn_registro use this class to style it as button

Comment: thank you for your help, one more thing please
which code should I enter ?

Comment: no no that was typo i have edited my answer it will work

Comment: Thank you, but it still looks like a link not a button

Comment: I have edited the answer and also include css code to make link a button. This will work as you expected and pls accept the answer if its done

Answer (score 1):

Button is for posting to server some form and inyour case do that via button is not right method. You must use

```
 CHtml::link('Link name', 'http://link.com')
```

and style like button via css, where you can add `a:hover` `a:active`.